# Context problem when running script from command line

Tags: command-line

The script below will run fine when executed from within Blender 3 (text panel), but if I try to run it through the command line, it fails on line 25 with bad context (on rotation).

Any hint will be greatly appreciated!

Thx!

````
import os
import sys
import bpy
import glob

convert_dir = "c:/tmp/2convert"

for file in os.listdir(convert_dir):
    if file.endswith(".svg"):      
        fullpath = convert_dir + "/" + file

for col in bpy.data.collections:
    if ("svg" in col.name):
        for oldobj in col.all_objects:
            bpy.data.objects.remove(oldobj)
        bpy.data.collections.remove(col)
        
fulloutputpath = os.path.splitext(fullpath)[0]+".svf"
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=False)
bpy.ops.import_curve.svg (filepath=fullpath)
for obj in bpy.data.collections[os.path.basename(fullpath)].all_objects:
    obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1.5708, orient_axis='X', orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(True, False, False), mirror=False, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    if ("Bleedline" in obj.name):
        bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 0.0005, 0), orient_axis_ortho='X', orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, True, False), mirror=False, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    obj.select_set(False)

bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx (filepath=fulloutputpath)
os.remove(fullpath)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

figured it out...

instead of doing the transformation with this:

`bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1.5708, orient_axis='X', orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(True, False, False), mirror=False, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)`

I did it at the object level:

```
eul = mathutils.Euler((math.radians(90), 0.0, 0.0), 'XYZ')
obj.rotation_euler = eul
```

Which seems to do the job